# R: Calculate percentages within groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a list of interviews conducted by two survey institutes A + B over a long period of time (several years) and a corresponding date variable:

```
date_of_interview  institute
--------------------------
2021-04-01         A
2021-04-01         A
2021-04-02         A
2021-04-02         A
2021-04-02         A
2021-04-02         B
2021-04-02         B
2021-04-02         B
etc.
```

All interviews should be evenly distributed over the weekdays (monday to friday). In order to check this, I would like to create the following graphic with a time variable on the x-axis (calendar weeks from 1-52):

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% mutate(weekday = format(date_of_interview, "%u"),
              week = format(date_of_interview, "%V"))
```

However, I am struggleing with calculating the percentages of the weekdays within the week-groups. All weekdays should be around 20% (mo-fr).

```r
ggplot(aes(x = week, fill = weekday, group = weekday)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack") +
  facet_wrap(institute ~.)
```

Comment: but what is y axis denoting?

Comment: Y axis denotes the percentage of each day within the week. The dotted areas could be wednesdays for example: If institute A conducted 20 interviews on monday and 100 interviews in week 1 then that field should be 20% and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want each facet to be an institute, each group per facet to be a weekday, and the filling to be the weekdays themselves. You can shuffle them around to suit your requirement if I have misunderstood.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    week = format(date_of_interview, "%V"),
    weekday = format(date_of_interview, "%u"),
    .keep='unused'
  ) %>% 
  group_by(institute, week, weekday) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n), .keep='unused') %>% 
  ungroup()
  
ggplot(df, aes(x=week, y=freq, fill=weekday)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  facet_wrap(institute ~.)
```

I tested on this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  date_of_interview = as.Date(c(
    '2021-04-01', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-02', '2021-04-02', 
    '2021-04-02', '2021-04-02', '2021-04-02', '2021-04-02', 
    '2021-04-09', '2021-04-10', '2021-04-11')),
  institute = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A')
)
```

Comment: Sure, I flipped the `group_by` operation to start with institute, then week, then weekday. Let me know if that's what you needed.